# A sequence Which is not weakly convergence

Tags: operator-theory

Let H be a infinite Hilbert space and $\{e_n\}$ be sn orthogonal sequence of projections in B(H)> Show that $\{ne_n: n\in N\}$ does not admit a subsequence converging to zero weakly.

I tried to proof it. suppose that there is a subsequence converging to zero weakly;but, I can not find a contradiction. Please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Choose any subsequence $\{n_k e_{n_k}\}$, and define
$$
y := \sum_k \frac{1}{n_k} e_{n_k}
$$
Check that $y$ is a well-defined element of $H$, and that
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} \langle n_k e_{n_k}, y\rangle = 1 \neq 0
$$
Hence, $n_k e_{n_k}$ does not converge to zero weakly.